# "Invalid ChangeSet : Id must be unique for each entry" error when inserting records from client using Ria Services SOAP endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, ria

I have a Silverlight application that uses Ria Services. I now wish to run a different client application (console application) that will perform certain scheduled day-end operations on the server. To do this and avoid duplication I have decided to expose the Ria Services DomainContext as a Web Service using SOAP as described [here](http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/josheastburn/josh-eastburn/2012/07/27/wcf-ria-services-toolkit-soap-endpoints) and [here](http://blog.hagenberg-software.at/2010/09/wcf-ria-services-v1-0-asp-net-client/) so that I can re-use the entities and relationships as set up in Ria Services without having to duplicate it in my client.

In my client I have successfully added the Service Reference and I am successfully able to query the Web Service to get results back. I am also able to perform an "insert" statement for a single new database entry. Unfortunately, the moment I add more than one item to my set of entries to update I get an error "Invalid ChangeSet : Id must be unique for each entry".

The following is my code:

```
DomainServiceSoapClient service = new DomainServiceSoapClient();
List<DomainServices.ChangeSetEntry> changesToSave = new List<DomainServices.ChangeSetEntry>();
foreach (string name in myListOfNames)
{
    Person newPerson = new Person() {Name = name};
    DomainServices.ChangeSetEntry entry = new DomainServices.ChangeSetEntry { Entity = newPerson, Operation = DomainServices.DomainOperation.Insert };
    changesToSave.Add(entry);
}
service.SubmitChanges(changesToSave.ToArray<DomainServices.ChangeSetEntry>());
```

The error occurs on the last line of the code. **As a test**, if I replace this last line with the following line (which means that I only have ONE entry in the array I am submitting) it works and I don't get the error.

```
service.SubmitChanges(new DomainServices.ChangeSetEntry[] {changesToSave.ToArray<DomainServices.ChangeSetEntry>()[0]});
```

How can I fix this so that SubmitChanges works when there is more than one entry I wish to submit?

Comment: Do you have a primary key on your table ?

Comment: Yes I do. The entire Silverlight application works just fine and everything in terms of Ria Services work from Silverlight. It is only from the Domain Service Soap Client side that this error is occurring.

Comment: Can whoever downvoted my question please give a pointer as to why they downvoted it to give me the opportunity to correct it and/or give additional information to make the question acceptable? If it simply appears as a downvoted question I run the risk of no-one looking at this question and I really need some input...

Comment: I didn't do that, why yor are not using service object for savechanges ?

Comment: That was a typing error when I typed my question, sorry. I have edited and corrected it in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use like, I assume that Person is your table.

```
DomainServiceSoapClient service = new DomainServiceSoapClient();
     foreach (string name in myListOfNames)
    {
        Person newPerson = new Person() {Name = name};
        service.Person.Add(newPerson);

    }
service.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: No, that is incorrect. That is the way one would do an insert and SubmitChanges on a Ria Servics DomainContext object in Silverlight. I am not working with a DomainContext here, I am working with a Domain Service (see the links I refer to in my question). The DomainService class does not expose an "Add" method and thus insert statements have to work as in the links in my question. (Unfortunately the links don't show an example where the set of changes can have more than one entry.)